# Problems with parameterizing timestamp references in PostgreSQL in Perl

Tags: sql, perl, postgresql

I am trying to use a parameterized query in a Perl script to get some timestamps back from a Postgres database. Here's a cut-and-dried example, solely for pedagogical purposes.

I've defined `$start_date` and `$end_date` as timestamps and intervals:

```
my $start_date = "current_timestamp - interval '6 hours'";
my $end_date = "current_timestamp";
```

I use the following to submit to the database, with `$dbh` defined earlier:

```
my $sql = "SELECT cast(? as timestamp), cast(? as timestamp)";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute($start_date, $end_date);
```

When I do this, I get a somewhat confusing error.

```
DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR:  date/time value "current" is no longer supported
```

I understand that `current` hasn't been supported in PG since 7.2, but I'm not using that. I'm using `current_timestamp`, which *is* supported, AFACT. To wit, if I enter into `psql`:

```
select (cast(current_timestamp - interval '6 hours' as timestamp), cast(current_timestamp as timestamp));
```

the result is what I expect (two timestamps, the former six hours previous to the latter).

I could also use `now()` rather than `current_timestamp`. I can use it in the following way:

```
my $start_date = "now() - interval '6 hours'"; 
my $end_date = "now()";
```

When I try to run the query in perl, I get the following error:

```
DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "now() - interval '6 hours'"
```

Yet, the query:

```
select (cast(now() - interval '6 hours' as timestamp), cast(now() as timestamp));
```

gives me the expected result.

I am quite flummoxed.

Comment: I think the syntax is wrong...The correct way should be like this $sth->execute($sql);

Comment: The syntax isn't wrong; I'm using the SQL and the database handle to create a statement handle using `prepare`, and then I'm using `execute` to run it with the appropriate parameters.

(I'm getting this both from existing (working) code in our codebase, along with the [DBI documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.628/DBI.pm).)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use a query with placeholder inside quotes? (perl / postgresql)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659737/how-can-i-use-a-query-with-placeholder-inside-quotes-perl-postgresql)

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, that's related, but not really a duplicate.

Comment: Do you intend `$start` and `$end` to be arbitrary pg expressions of timestamps?  Or will they always be offsets from "now"?  (And, if so, will the offsets always be in hours?)

Comment: @pilcrow: They will generally be offsets from now, but in a later version I want to allow for fixed periods too. The offsets vary -- from a ten minute window to a week, and in between times of 6 hours, 12 hours, 1 day, 3 days, and so forth.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that a SQL placeholder doesn't represent an expression, but a single value.  And that value can't be a function.  You could do something like:

```
my $start_date = "6 hours";
my $sql = "SELECT current_timestamp - cast(? as interval), current_timestamp";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute($start_date);
```

What you're doing in Perl is equivalent to doing this in `psql`:

```
select (cast('current_timestamp - interval ''6 hours''' as timestamp), cast('current_timestamp' as timestamp));
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried that, and I got the following error:  

`DBD::Pg::st execute failed: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "$1"`  

and made no mention of `$start_date` or its contents (6 hours), which I did pass in. Trying it by setting `$start_date = "'6 hours'";` yields the same error.

Comment: Apparently, PostgreSQL doesn't let you say `INTERVAL ?`, you have to say `CAST(? AS INTERVAL)`.  And the outer cast is redundant, because a timestamp minus an interval is already a timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

To make the windows of your queries a bit more flexible:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare(<<__eosql);
SELECT * FROM tbl
 WHERE ts BETWEEN current_timestamp - ? * CAST('1 ' || ? AS INTERVAL)
                  AND
                  current_timestamp;
__eosql

$sth->execute(6, 'hour');
$sth->execute(10, 'day');
$sth->execute(1, 'week');
# etc.
```

When you introduce fixed time points, you could do something too clever like `... WHERE COALESCE(?, current_timestamp) ...` and remember that an `undef` parameter defaults to the current time.  However, I'd probably write and prepare a separate query.