# mysql and perl - adding variable into query

Tags: mysql, perl

Hi all you mysql and perl gurus!

I have code that looks like
    $store = qq(INSERT INTO main (release_date) VALUES(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))

It works perfectly. The problem is I need to find a way to use a variable instead of "INTERVAL 1 DAY". This value is coming from a form and has about 12 options (ie: 1 Day, 2 Day, 1 Week, 2 Week).

I'm currently using 12 different if/elsif conditions based on the form variables so the code right now is really bulky.

I'm trying to get something like this to work
    var timeframe = "";
    if ($data{date_field} == "1 Week")
    {
        $timeframe = "1 WEEK";
    }
    .
    .
        $store = qq(INSERT INTO main (release_date) VALUES(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL "$timeframe"))

But it errors out saying I have a MySQL syntax problem.

Anyone know what I have to do to get this to work so I can shorten the code a bit?

Comment: perhaps the problem is the quotes. I would try removing the quotes from around $timeframe.  Can you output the value of store before running it? lets see what it is.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10659737/how-can-i-use-a-query-with-placeholder-inside-quotes-perl-postgresql

Comment: I strongly encourage you to heed the advice in your previous question to *use placeholders* in your SQL statement, and do the `prepare` only once.

Answer (score 3):

Lose the quotes; `$bar = "baz"; qq(foo $bar)` will be `foo baz`, while `qq(foo "$bar")` gives you `foo "baz"`, which you don't want in this case.

However, specifically for SQL, this approach is somewhat dangerous. In your case it is fine, since you're setting the value of `$timeframe` yourself; but if there is a faintest possibility of user input getting in there, you can have a [Bobby Tables incident](http://bobby-tables.com). Specifically, study the [Perl page](http://bobby-tables.com/perl.html) there.

Comment: Thank you!  That was absolutely what I needed! It works great!